# Replace pages with static HTML pages

Tags: 7

I have a drupal 7 driven website.
I need to replace a handful of pages on that website using static HTML without impacting the URLs of those pages.

For example I have a page accessible at: example.com/services/
That page is a proper drupal driven page. I want that page to display a proper HTML page I've written from scratch without any input from drupal engine but still retain the same URL so anything that leads to that page (internal & external links) would continue to work.

What's the correct way to set that up.
Thank you!

Comment: 2 ways. 1.- place your html in body and set full HTML, 2.- override tpl.php template

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Looking into it now I realized that these are not "pages" but some custom content types called "service".

Comment: If you are able, I would recommend creating the page(s) in a custom module for full control. It really depends on whether or not you are utilizing drupal regions or if the page is 100% custom HTML.

Comment: The replacement pages are 100% custom HTML. I ended up using this module to achieve what I need: https://www.drupal.org/project/static_page

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the answer is still the same now as it would have been then. Drupal only kicks in if a file does not exist at the given URL and path. For example, if you try to access the following path on a Drupal instance, where nonexistentfile.html does not exist, Drupal will kick in and show a Drupal 404 message:

```
/[WEBROOT]/some/path/nonexistantfile.html
```

However, if you then create a file with that name at that location, that file wil be picked up rather than Drupal kicking in.

So the answer to the question is to create an .html file, and place it on the server at the required location, and it will be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

lets say your url is : example.com/services , and services is 1 content type of drupal , and if you want to replace whole page with static html them create **services.html** page on root folder of your drupal and add whole html inside it and then run url it will display only html added in that html file.

Note : this html file name must be same as url , if url is **example.com/abc** then file name should be **abc.html**

Hope this helps you.